# Other options for sending Emails from PHP

Tags: php, paypal, scripting, paypal-ipn

So having a massive issue in my PayPal IPN script, as soon as I add an Email sending script, the whole code stops working?! No matter where I try to add it, top, bottom, middle, between the if statements, anywhere - it stops the entire IPN. My question is

Is there any different options to sending Emails rather than using the `mail()` script? My code is below...

```
$subject = "BES WebDesign";
    $message = "Dear $first_name $last_name,

    Thank you for ordering from BES WebDesign, we are here to help you every step of the way. You can use the following details to login to our aPanel to check the process of your order(s) and control any outstanding order(s) you may already have...

    http://apanel.basecentre.co.uk

    Email: $payer_email
    Password: $txn_id

    If you have any issues with BES WebDesign or our aPanel, please feel free to contact us and one of our team members will provide help and support.

    Thanks!
    BaseCenter Admin Team

    This is an automated response, please do not reply!";

    mail($payer_email, $subject, $message, "From: BaseCentre<admin@basecentre.co.uk>\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

If anybody knows of a reason the IPN script won't allow me to add this in, I would be appreciative of knowing - otherwise, if anybody has any other idea's of how I can do this task, I would love to know... Such as, maybe using a different script to send a notification email as soon as the MySQL database has been updated? I only have hourly cron jobs so wouldn't be the best idea but if I can initiate it somehow once the IPN is sent, that would be ideal ?

Thanks!

Comment: Place the mailing function after a successful method. What you posted doesn't show us where in your script it is failing.

Comment: Yeah I have done that on purpose, because it really doesn't make much sense, even after I post the script after a successful method, it still stops it from working? Plus, I added the script beforehand and the post was deleted? Not sure why?

Comment: *Hm....* most bizarre. Well, I for one cannot provide a solution.

Comment: Do you get any errors? `error_reporting(E_ALL)` maybe will give you some clues?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to view the errors as I would not be on the page ?

Comment: Check this [guide on testing PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) to see tips on seeing the result in your browser so you can troubleshoot and resolve issues.